# Как указать столбцам DataGridView определённый тип данных

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Что я имею ввиду: допустим в dataGrid есть столбец с типом int, но в него можно вписать данные типа string, что приведёт к исключению. Как можно это обойти?

Comment: ловить исключение через `try-catch`? не писать туда неправильные данные? изменить тип столбца?

Comment: В окошке, которое показывается по умолчанию, написано же, что нужно обработать событие [DataError](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). И смотрите [Walkthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/handling-errors-that-occur-during-data-entry-in-the-datagrid?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) и [How to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/handle-errors-that-occur-during-data-entry-in-the-datagrid?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).